# Wondering how to set up my database for a season long football pool

Tags: php, mysql

Total newb at this, but I think it's a good learning project.

I want to set up a football season prediction pool for me and some friends.  I want to have results for each week and for the season as a whole.

What I was thinking was, I would have one table for each week of the season.  It would need to track the home team and the road team for each game of that week.  Then another table for each players picks each week.

Does this make sense, or should I put the whole season in a table, in which case I would have to add the week # as another column?

Just any general advice on how to get started would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Any solution which calls for multiple tables based on some varying parameter is generally the wrong one. You split tables after performance on single monolithic tables becomes an issue, not before.

Comment: "Any solution which calls for multiple tables based on some varying parameter is generally the wrong one"  Thank you, that's the sort of general knowledge I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

better option to have whole season in one table and add week column in it. and its will be easy to query just one table, in other case you have to query 4 or 5 different tables for each week, if you have different seasons also like 2012, 2013 and so on then create a separate season table and linked it to week table for example

```
season table columns
 id,season_name,start_date,end_date,publish

week table
 id,season_id,game_date,team1,team2
```